# Range data annotation not working

Tags: c#, range, asp.net-core, data-annotations, modelstate

In my web api project I have

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]AccountDTO accountDto)
```

AccountDto include some properties, for example:

```
public int AccountId { get; protected set; }
    [Range(0,100)]
    public int AccountBalance { get; protected set; }
    [RegularExpression(COMMA_SEPARATED_EMAILS_REGEX)]
    public string Emails { get; set; }
```

I also added filter to catch model errors:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException(string.Join(" ", context.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => context.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(x => key + ": " + x.ErrorMessage))));
        }
    }
```

Now, if the email string not valid - it throw the expected error, also I tried `[EmailAddress], [Phone], [Required], [StringLength(3)]`, and all working OK.
just [Range(0,100)] not working...

I tried post AccountDTO with accountBallance = 50033333 and no error thrown, also tried -5 and I got status 200.

where should I look for the bug?... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this maybe it help :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "AccountBalance is required")]
[Range(1.00, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "AccountBalance must be between 1 and 100")]
public Double AccountBalance { get; protected set; }
```

and make sure you are using  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations  .

Answer (score 1):

Once I removed the `protected` the validation work.

Comment: Same, changing mine from private to public worked.